# Removing extra spaces from a string

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
"This is     a string".split.join(' ')
# => "This is a string"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#squeeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

> Returns a new string where runs of the same character that occur in this set are replaced by a single character.

```
'This is     a string'.squeeze(' ')
#=> "This is a string"
```

Note that `squeeze` does not remove (single) leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: string.squeeze(' ') has been slower than string.split.join(' ') in tests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8682562/4304188

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu the OP is asking for a *more elegant* way, not for a faster one.

Comment: Would the down-voter leave a comment, please?

Comment: Actually the OP was asking for the "best way". But someone edited this question.

Comment: No, I indeed asked for the most elegant way rather that the fastest way, but good to know .split.join is faster.

Comment: @user2914693 not necessarily, on my system `squeeze(' ')` is actually faster than `split.join(' ')`

Comment: Interesting. On my system .squeeze executes in .000027 seconds and .split.join in 0.00057 seconds. Perhaps it depends on the data.